# Some buttons are illegible (probably a CSS issue)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There seems to be a design (CSS?) bug on the main site.  Look at this button in the "edit profile" settings:

[image: brown-on-brown save button]

Here is the corresponding page on a different site:

[image: Workplace page]

It's not just that button; I encountered this problem when handling flags using a [prototype for a revised flag overlay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306190/162102) written by a CM.  When I reported the bug there, he found that it's an underlying design bug on this site specifically.

I believe the pattern on other sites is that the *text color* in the circled box matches the usual button color, and the *background color* comes from something else on the site.  We're not getting the expected background color here.

Comment: I noticed this issue immediately after the recent redesign of the top bar, but I thought it was a bad design decision so I didn't make any mention of it.

Comment: @Ploni if you notice something weird, please report.  If it's intentional and bad, that draws more attention so maybe we can get it fixed.  If (as in this case) it's a bug, they can't fix it if they don't know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Fix for this bug is ready and should be up on site in couple hours. Consider this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Much better -- thanks!