# Another CSS issue with the save button?

Tags: bug, design

[This post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4500/9643) indicated a CSS  issue with the save button on the "edit profile" page. It seems that this issue (or a related one) has cropped up again. This is what the page looks like by me:

[image]

And here is what it looks like on superuser:

[image]

Regardless of what the underlying issue is, I can't see the save button until I hover over it.

Comment: Reproduced.  I'm seeing white text on a light background.  The button turns a darker orange/brown on hover and *then* you can read the text, but not without mouse assist.